# Plot python binance

Tags: python, websocket

La salida de este codigo websockets de binance en su orden es Lado(Sell o Buy), fecha, precio y cantidad asi:

```
BUY, 2019-08-19 20:11:06, 0.01845700, 0.11900000

BUY, 2019-08-19 20:11:06, 0.01846000, 0.09700000

SELL, 2019-08-19 20:11:06, 0.01845600, 0.00700000

SELL, 2019-08-19 20:11:09, 0.01845700, 0.78800000
```

Quisiera graficar modo heatmap como este link https://epochjs.github.io/epoch/real-time/#heatmap los valores asi:

En el eje X Precio, en el eje Y el Fecha(tiempo) y cada cuadro del heatmap esta dado por la cantidad pero si es "SELL" es roja pero si es "BUY" debe ser azul.

```
    from binance.client import Client
    from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager 
    from datetime import datetime
    import time

    PUBLIC = 'your public'
    SECRET = 'your key'

    client = Client(api_key=PUBLIC, api_secret=SECRET)
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)

    def handle_message(msg):

      if msg['e'] == 'error':    
           print(msg['m'])
      else:
           timestamp = msg['T'] / 1000
           timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
           if msg['m'] == True:
                event_side = 'SELL'
           else:
                event_side = 'BUY '
           # print final side(color), date, price and qty
           print("{}, {}, {}, {}".format(event_side, timestamp, 
   msg['p'], msg['q']))
   conn_key = bm.start_trade_socket('ETHBTC', handle_message)
   bm.start()
   time.sleep(5)
   bm.stop_socket(conn_key)
```

Debido a que son websockets debería ser un grafico tipo streaming de datos continuos.

Comment: ¿Has pensado que librería piensas usar para la gráfica? Matplotlib, Bokeh, seaborn, plotly, etc...

Comment: Hola, si gracias intente utilizar plotly pero no logre realizar el gráfico.